# Cannot run Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I tried to run Android emulator from Android Studio, this error dialog always popped up

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Windows 7 or newer is required to run the Android Emulator.

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anyone have idea why is this happening? It came suddenly

Currently I'm using Windows 7 Professional

Notes: It's weird but I can run the emulator through the command line

Comment: Have you checked requirement in developer site? For example they say 

"Your computer must have an Intel processor with support for the following:

   1. Intel VT-x
   2. Intel EM64T (Intel 64)
   3. Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality enabled

Comment: But, I can run the emulator through the command line